# JsonResult takes only the first parameter and ignores the rest

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I am having a strange issue that is up above my level, I tried to troubleshoot the issue without luck.

I am developing a simple MVC application and I am using ajax to send data from a view to controller. For some reason, the controller only recognized the fist parameters and the rest are just nulls. I even tried to put fixed strings instead of variables but they still appear as null from the controller???

The view:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Home/AddItem",
        data: "{ItemModel: 'ttt1', ItemName: 'ttt2'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            if (data.Success == "Success") {
                alert("Item has been added.");
            } else {
                alert("We were not able to create the offer");
            }
        },
        error: function (exception) {                
            console.log(exception);
        }
    });
```

On the Home controller, I have the below action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddItem(string ItemModel, string ItemName)//ItemName is always null??
    {
        try
        {
            _DB.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO ITEMS(iModel, iName) VALUES ({0}, {1})", ItemModel, ItemName);
            return Json(new { Success = "Success" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending the data correctly.

The code indicates JSON but is sending just a single string. If you inspect `ItemModel`, I am certain it will contain the string data sent from the client.

Create a JavaScript object and then stringify that as the body of the request.

```
var payload = { ItemModel: 'ttt1', ItemName: 'ttt2' }; //<-- create object
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../Home/AddItem",
    data: JSON.stringify(payload), //<-- properly format for request
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        if (data.Success == "Success") {
            alert("Item has been added.");
        } else {
            alert("We were not able to create the offer");
        }
    },
    error: function (exception) {                
        console.log(exception);
    }
});
```

The model binder should then be able to differentiate the desired parameters.

Ideally when expecting data in the body of a request it is better to use a model

```
public class Item {
    public string ItemModel { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
```

And have the action explicitly look for it in the body of the request using the `FromBody` attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddItem([FromBody]Item item) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        try {
            var sql = @"INSERT INTO ITEMS(iModel, iName) VALUES ({0}, {1})";
            _DB.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, item.ItemModel, item.ItemName);
            return Json(new { Success = "Success" });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    return Json(new { Success = "BadRequest" });         
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out and get back to you in a moment.

Comment: It didn't work, I get the same thing, the second parameter is null?? I am out of ideas, but I will keep trying

Comment: Thank you very much, I had the most strange issue... I have deleted the controller method and wrote a new one from scratch and it worked. The new controller method has different name but exactly the same content! I have no explanation to this at all